# Using itext to get height and width?

Tags: vb.net

I have tried but couldn't get proper output.Code has been placed below.

```
Dim Height, Width As Double
Dim reader As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader = Nothing
Dim doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document()

reader = New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(FILENAME)

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(FILENAME,FileMode.Open))

doc.Open()
Height = doc.PageSize.Height
Width = doc.PageSize.Width
Height = Math.Round(Height)
Width = Math.Round(Width)
doc.Close()
```